# Answer This Daily Puzzle

Tags: english, language

<sup>[Source of Puzzle](https://gpuzzles.com/mind-teasers/3-letter-english-verb/?source=stack)</sup>

Can you name a three letter English verb that becomes its past tense simply by moving the first letter to the end?

Comment: Just so you know, on this site it's common practice to accept the first answer posted out of multiple identical answers, which in this case would be [ʇolɐǝz ǝɥʇ qoq's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/51410/30903).

Answer (score 12):

An answer could be:

> Eat

becomes

> Ate

Comment: Beat me by 30 seconds :-)

Comment: @randal'thor hmm apparently there are now 3 same answers XD

Comment: @SheldonCooper Please accept the earliest answer, which is this one. Even if it's by... what, 35 seconds?

Answer (score 6):

The verb

> EAT

has past tense

> ATE.

Answer (score 6):

This is an interesting question (with an answer already), so I thought I'd explore the pattern a bit more with a script and a dictionary of English words.  It turns out that there are a few related words if you remove the limitation of "verb":

- aye -> yea  - two forms of an affirmative response
- car -> arc  - two types of vehicles
- eli -> lie  - is Eli dishonest?  ;)
- ewe -> wee (->eew)  - a bit of a stretch, but two reactions (disgust, excitement?)
- gen -> eng  - two abbreviations for job titles (general, engineer)
- now -> own  - sounds like a commercial?  ("Now own the world's greatest...")
- sad -> ads  - ??  (There is a joke here somewhere...)
- tar -> art  - a new genre of art?
- who -> how  - two of the five basic questions (who, what, when,
  where, how)

Comment: The vehicle is an ark.